# How do I make an Image inherit its parent's size? (React Native)

Tags: image, reactjs, react-native, flexbox

Here's the layout I'd like:

[image: Desired layout]

Here's what happens when I add an image:

[image: Current layout]

I'd like Image to respect its parent sizing. How would I do that?

Answer (score 4):

try styling the image to

```
     width: null,
     height: null,
     flex: 1
```

Comment: width: null sets width to 0

Answer (score 1):

I ended up calculating the width of the image manually by just doing this:

```
screenWidth/7 - margin
```

This is a hack, so if anyone has a proper way of doing it I'd love to hear it!